# How to find the Maclaurin series

Tags: taylor-expansion

How can I find the Maclaurin series.

$\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ ((-1)^ k }{\pi}^{2k}$/($9^k(2k)!$)

Please, help me how to solve this. Show how to do this.

Comment: The Maclaurin series of a constant?!

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\cos (x)= \sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }\frac{ (-1)^ k x^{2k}}{(2k)!} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @josh Instead of saying 'please, help me', why not show what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Remember that $$\cos u=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k\frac{u^{2k}}{(2k)!}.$$

*Some details*

In the present case, we have to identify $\dfrac{\pi^2}{9k}$ with $u^{2k}$, which yields $u^{2k}=\\Bigl(\dfrac\pi3\Bigr)^{2k}$, 
so  the sum of the series is $\cos\dfrac\pi3$.

Comment: I have the answer as cos(pi/9). But, can you please show me the process as it will be very helpful in understanding the problem.

Comment: @josh Shouldn't the answer be a series?

Comment: I have no idea so I am asking how to solve this problem

Comment: @josh: I've added  details. Is that clearer?